# Is there a way to use aliases for Sass @use with Vite?

Tags: sass, vite

This may be a fairly noob question, but I haven't yet been able to find a solution that works.

I am trying to use an alias for the @use/@forward methods with Sass in conjunction with Sass modules/CSS modules in a React project using Vite.

For example, I want to be able to use `@use "@scss/styles"` from the something.module.scss without the use of `@use "../scss/styles"`

Example folder structure below:

```
└── My-App/
    └── src/
        ├── scss/
        │   ├── styles.scss
        │   └── abstract/
        │       └── _colors.scss
        └── components/
            └── something.module.scss
```

My understanding is that aliases via the vite.config.ts don't apply to the Sass preprocessor as they currently work normally for everything else.

There is a `sass-alias` package on npm [sass-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-alias), however I have not been able to make it work via the config file. From what I can understand, it also uses a non-current method to achieve.

Most of what I have seen apply mostly to Webpack, and don't seem to work in my case. Various iterations of filenames have been tried as well as putting aliases in the `vite.config.ts` and `tsconfig.json` files.

I have tried using the `sass-alias` package without too much success as well. I think I'm missing something really obvious, or that the solution will involve a combination of using `path` and resolving `__dirname` with a combination of other things I'm not familiar with.

Many thanks in advance.